# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I created a new database on Heroku using a follower. After it was 0 commits behind I unfollow the master db and promote it as default.

Seems to be working fine but looks to be read only. When I try to seve a record from the console now I see this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'd say your replica didn't actually get promoted. What does `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` report?

Comment: I didn't release the follower. Now seems to be working fine.

Comment: Followers are always Read Only.

Comment: @Martin How do you release a follower? I promoted a database and am seeing these issues, but it's unclear to me what I should do.

Comment: Ah, "release" means running "heroku pg:unfollow", to make it no longer an follower, and to make it read-write. Some more info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#3-promote-follower.

Comment: I got this error when I promoted before first doing an unfollow. I removed the problematic DB (the read-only one), created a new follower, did pg:unfollow and pg:promote on that new follower. Then everything worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422248/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgreadonlysqltransaction-heroku-database-st/46435348#46435348

Comment: Ran into the same problem can we not do `set transaction read write;` to fix this problem.

I am not able to create a follower as well as I keep getting this error `An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create heroku-postgresql:standard-2: The database you are attempting to follow is  still too new. Please try again later.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replica never actually got promoted. See comments.

You can tell when a replica is following a master server because:

```
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
```

will return true. This cannot return true in a master server because the only time a master server can be in recovery is when it is still starting up - and then you cannot connect to it, so you can't run that command. That's true as of 9.2 and 9.3beta; this may change in future versions, so if you're reading this and on a newer version check for a dedicated function for checking if the server is a replica.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations you need to explicitly set write mode on your active record console. Try running:

`readwrite!`

This might not be directly relevant to Heroku consoles, but figured I'd post here for anyone needing this particular solution.