# Heroku server is stuck in recovery mode. Not responding to anything

Tags: database, heroku, psql, readonly, pg

This error is consistent throughout our Heroku hosted DB :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute SELECT FOR UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

Strange. We did nothing to the database recently.

In `heroku pg:psql` I run this :

```
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
```

Which returns:

```
 pg_is_in_recovery 
-------------------
 t
 (1 row)
```

I tried this in `psql` :

```
#> set transaction read write;
ERROR:  cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery
```

No idea how this might have happened. We did nothing to the server.

The question is, how do we make it stop?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm in the same situation after promoting a database from follower on Heroku. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223870/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error-cannot-execute-update-in-a-rea gives me the impression that it is somehow still considered a follower, but I'm not sure how to recover from it, other than try to remove and re-add this DB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422248/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgreadonlysqltransaction-heroku-database-st/46435348#46435348