# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: - Heroku database still read only even after unfollow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I wanted to copy a database from one app to another in heroku. I have an issue with indexes forcing me to do this using a follower db and then unfollowing.

My problem is that now after creating the follower, unfollowing, and promoting it i'm getting an error when trying to write to it:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute ALTER TABLE in a read-only transaction`

Also, when I run: `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` I get true

What I did was:
`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-4  –follow MAIN_DB_ADDON_NAME -a app-that-follows`

`heroku pg:unfollow HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL -a app-that-follows`

`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL -a app-that-follows`

Any idea why i'm getting this error, and more importantly, *how do I solve it*??

Thanks,
Uri

Answer (score 2):

After a while the database became writable again. I'm attaching the answer I got from heroku support:

> When you unfollowed the primary database, was the follower completely up to date? If the follower has a bunch of built up WAL it can sometimes leave the database in recovery until it is able to ro replay all of the WAL.

And indeed when you do a `pg:info` and have a follower db you can see a `Behind By` field showing you how many commits your follower is behind by.

Mine was way behind, so it took it a while to catch up...

Probably a good idea to add this to the heroku postgres documentation